# 1062 Duplicate entry 'emma@ohp-abudhabi.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my laravel project , i try to make the email unique for the user , and to get an error as an alert not a laravel error , how can i get the error as an alert however i used :

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li> {{$error}}</li>
@endforeach
```

The migration:

```
 public function up()
 {
     Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->id();
         $table->string('name');
         $table->string('usertype')->nullable();
         $table->string('email')->unique();
         $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
         $table->string('password');
         $table->rememberToken();
         $table->timestamps();
     });
 }
```

The view where I insert the new user:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li> {{$error}}</li>
@endforeach

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('users.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
              
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name (1 word)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required >
               
    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">firstname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" required>
             
    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">lastname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this throwing the error when you run the migration, or when you run some app code

Comment: i can see the error when i try to adda new user with a used email before for an other one !

Comment: You need to handle that error in the code you've omitted from the question (where you actually are dong the insert). Since you seem to be using Laravel's validation, you could simply add a check in that validation to see if the email is unique: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Then I would show us the code from where the error is happening

Comment: i edited the post please check it

Comment: If you're trying to add another user with the same email of an existing user your table schema prevents this. Do you want to allow duplicate emails in your table? Then modify your schema

Comment: You get this error when you add new users, so showing us your view is rather useless

Comment: @apokryfos I don't want to allow duplicated email , i just want to get an error as an alert if someone try to registered with an other used email , that's all !

Comment: The error is a valid error to see. You might want to use something like [unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) to have the opportunity to provide better feedback to the user, but some sort of error  is going to be necessary.  Errors don't necessarily mean bugs in your code sometimes they mean your code is preventing you from doing something that you're not supposed to